# Spring Oauth authorization code configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

How do I properly configure my jdbcAuthorizationCodeService?

So here's a gist of my configuration

```
  @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                    .authorizationCodeServices(this.jdbcAuthorizationCodeServices).userApprovalHandler(new DefaultUserApprovalHandler());
        }
```

and my table is constructed like this

[image]

My question is. what are the sample values of the authentication column should be? since it's bytea, as required by spring oauth2

Answer (score 0):

The authentication column will store a serialized version of OAuth2Authentication object received in a call.

This is the code from jdbcAuthorizationCodeService class

```
@Override
    protected void store(String code, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(insertAuthenticationSql,
                new Object[] { code, new 
SqlLobValue(SerializationUtils.serialize(authentication)) }, new int[] {
                        Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB });
    }
```